# AngularJS - Why isn't my checkbox keeping state with my ng-model property?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

In my angular app I have a view with a checkbox on it and it's `ng-model` property is tied to `search.includeRemote`.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-change="getJobs()" ng-model="search.includeRemote" /></label>
```

In my controller, I have the following code.

```
$scope.getJobs = function () {
    var url = '/jobs/page/' + $scope.page +
            '/pageSize/' + $scope.pageSize +
            '/?keyword=' + encodeURI($scope.search.keyword) +
            '&includeRemote=' + $scope.search.includeRemote;
    $location.url(url);
};

$scope.init = function () {
    var s = $location.search();
    $scope.page = $routeParams.page || '1';
    $scope.pageSize = $routeParams.pageSize || '5';
    $scope.search = {
        keyword: s.keyword || '',
        includeRemote: s.includeRemote || true
    };
};

$scope.loadJobs = function () {
    searchParams = {
        pageSize: $scope.pageSize.toString(),
        page: $scope.page.toString(),
        keyword: $scope.search.keyword,
        includeRemote: $scope.search.includeRemote
    };

    jobService.loadJobs(searchParams).then(function(data){
        angular.forEach(data.jobs, function(d) {
            d.timeFrame = $filter('figureTimeFrame')(d.receivedDate);
        }, $scope.jobs);

        $scope.jobs = data.jobs;
        $scope.page = data.page > 1 ? data.page : 1;
        $scope.pages = data.pages;
        $scope.jobCount = data.jobCount;
        $scope.salaryFacets = data.salaryFacets;
        $scope.titleFacets = data.titleFacets;
        $scope.jobTypeFacets = data.jobTypeFacets;
        $scope.locationFacets = data.locationFacets;
        $scope.includeRemoteFacets = data.includeRemoteFacets;
        $scope.setSelectedFilters();
    });
};

$scope.init();
$scope.loadJobs();
```

The issue is that when the page first loads, `$scope.search.includeRemote` is set to `true` and the checkbox in the view reflects that as being checked.  If I uncheck the checkbox it reloads the page, leaving it unchecked and the `$scope.search.includeRemote` property is `false`.  However, if I then try to check the checkbox it reloads the page, sets the `$scope.search.includeRemote` property to `true`, but this time the checkbox is not checked.  Something is happening where angular is not tying the value of `includeRemote` to the checked value of the checkbox but for the life of me I can't figure out why.  Oh, and to confirm my model's `search.includeRemote` property is in fact being set correctly I have another section of the view with `{{search.includeRemote}}` which is writing out `true` to the page.

ANSWER:

I can't believe I didn't think of this earlier but it all came down to the querystring parameter being treated as a string instead of a boolean value.  Here's my updated init function that now allows the page to work.

```
$scope.init = function () {
    var s = $location.search();
    var incRemote = true;
    if (s.includeRemote){
        incRemote = s.includeRemote === 'true';
    }
    $scope.page = $routeParams.page || '1';
    $scope.pageSize = $routeParams.pageSize || '5';
    $scope.search = {
        keyword: s.keyword || '',
        includeRemote: incRemote
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this issue is to send your ng-model value as a parameter in getJobs() function, this works fin in many cases.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-change="getJobs(search.includeRemote)" ng-model="search.includeRemote" />
```

and in your controller you can get the actual state like this.

```
$scope.getJobs=function(search.includeRemote){
  if(search.includeRemote===true){
     console.log(search.includeRemote)    
   }
}
```

**EDIT**
Sorry i have ready your code completely.

```
$scope.getJobs = function (state) {
var url = '/jobs/page/' + $scope.page +
        '/pageSize/' + $scope.pageSize +
        '/?keyword=' + encodeURI($scope.search.keyword) +
        '&includeRemote=' + state;
sessionStorage.setItem('state', state);
$location.url(url);
};
```

add this in your controller it will work

get checkbox state when page goes to new location

```
$scope.search.includeRemote=sessionStorage.getItem('state');
```

Comment: Sorry that's not working either.  My scope.search.includeRemote property IS being set to the correct value of what is in the querystring when the page reloads after the url refresh but the checkbox just isn't getting it's checked property set.

Comment: OK then store your checkbox state in session storage . and get this state back when page goes to new location.

Comment: I get the same behavior whether I use sessionStorage or the url parameter.  The includeRemote property is true, but the checkbox doesn't get checked.

Comment: This is a common behaviour in angularjs you can use jquery to solve this.

Comment: have you try $scope.$apply() after this ?